# How to save text from console to a string in C (Windows platform)

Tags: c, windows, console

I'm currently building a console app for a school project and I really need this function for my app.

How do I save all the text from console to a string in C (Windows platform)?

For example:

If I used the function `system("dir")`, it will output to console and list all the subdirectories and files in a directory. And I want it to be saved on a string for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`popen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) rather than `system()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    fp = popen("DIR", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        /* Handle error */
    }

    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", path);
    }

    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
**popen() function:**

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html

The popen() function shall execute the command specified by the string command. It shall create a pipe between the calling program and the executed command, and shall return a pointer to a stream that can be used to either read from or write to the pipe.

#include 
    ...

```
FILE *fp;
int status;
char path[PATH_MAX];


fp = popen("ls *", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;


while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL
    printf("%s", path);
```

This works on Linux. So i think it might also works in windows.

Comment: Ah. Was gonna answer the same thing.

Comment: i and Johnsyweb has posted the same answer at almost same time...!!